# removed spaces and tabs in python code but still error coming

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, python-requests

**update1:**

- that error went away but now I am getting another error,
- providing it below..
- can you tell me how to fix it

  Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "python", line 20
          except IOError:
               ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**code**

```
from socket import *                                   
sports = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
player = socket.getplayerbyname() 
port = 6789
sports.bind(player. port)
while True:     
    print 'sky...'     
    stars, addr =   sports.accept() 
    try:         
        bat =  help.html      
        ball = bat.split()[1]                          
        f = open(ball[1:])                                 
        outputdata = f.read()

        print stars.send("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")     

        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):                         
          stars.send(outputdata[i])          
          stars.close()     
        except IOError:         

        print stars.send(404 NOT FOUND) 
        stars.close()
        sports.close()
```

- I am new to python.
- I am trying to run a for the loop.
- but I am getting an error.
- I tried removing spaces and tabs but still facing the issue.
- can you tell me how to fix it?
- providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
from socket import *                                   
sports = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
player = socket.getplayerbyname() 
port = 6789
sports.bind(player. port)
while True:     
    print 'sky...'     
    stars, addr =   sports.accept() 
    try:         
        bat =  help.html      
        ball = bat.split()[1]                          
        f = open(ball[1:])                                 
        outputdata = f.read()

        print stars.send("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")     

         for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):                         
            stars.send(outputdata[i])          
         stars.close()     
except IOError:         

        print stars.send(404 NOT FOUND) 
        stars.close()
sports.close()
```

**error**

Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1
    for bat in range(0, len(sports)):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: The line in the traceback doesn't appear anywhere in the code you have given.

Comment: The line `for bat in range(0, len(sports))` doesn't appear in the code you've provided ... the only for-loop you show *does look* like it is indented with respect to the previous line, a `print` which would cause that error.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858969/indentationerror-in-for-loop Is this a repost?

Comment: @all: hey I am getting another error...can you tell me how to fix it ----> Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 20 except IOError: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You have one extra space in your code that starts on

```
         for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
```

Notice how the start of the `for` line doesn't match up with the start of the `print` line above it?

Comment: hey I am getting another error...can you tell me how to fix it ----> Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 20 except IOError: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: your `except` line needs to start on the same level of indentation as your `try` line too

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is a space right in front of your `for` statement. Remove that and the error should be gone